# In The Wall Jumper, what is the meaning of the very last line about walls still standing?

Tags: meaning, german-language, peter-schneider, the-wall-jumper

In *The Wall Jumper* by Peter Schneider the very last line is:

> The city outside, with its fire walls, garden walls, border walls - those  walls will still be standing when no one is left to move beyond them.

My first impression of this line is that it means the physical walls will outlast humanity, which seems to me to be wrong and not really consistent with the book.

If someone could enlighten me as to the meaning of this line in the book, that would be amazing.

Comment: What is your opinion?